# выборка двух ссылок из документа и их склеивание

Tags: javascript, html

добрый день прошу помощи.
есть структура html:

```
    <div class="song-info song-play ">
      <div class="song-title">
        <a title="Ether" href="/ru/a35184372149697/al56c79bbf75c08ebf259759f7/t56c79bbf75c08ebf259759f8"> Ether </a>
      </div>
      <div class="song-artist">
        <a href="/ru/a35184372149697" title="Mogwai">Mogwai</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Я хочу получить в массив или объект текст ссылок Ether Mogwai
Для этого с цикле обхожу весь html:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('song-title');
var x1 = document.getElementsByClassName('song-artist');
```

получаю массив: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но потом никак не могу выбрать текст ссылки и склеить их вместе. Делаю так:

```
x[1].childNodes
```

получаю:  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Потом хочу получть имя песни:
    x[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUojC.png).childNodes.title; // undefined

[Сайт, название песен с которого пытаюсь получить](http://tidido.com/ru/u17592186065408/playlists/565756fc3fa4df654c8b4567)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

список всех песен

```
list = document.getElementsByClassName('song-info song-play ')
```

cooтветственно

```
list[1].childNodes[3].childNodes[1].title  // назвние группы

list[1].childNodes[1].childNodes[1].title  // название песни
```